# Accessing $dirty property of component that does not include a <form> element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a component in my AngularJS 1.6 app that dynamically generates checkboxes using `ng-repeat`, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="subItem in item.ChildItemTypes">
    <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="subItem.checked">{{ subItem.Description }}</md-checkbox>
</div>
```

This component does not contain a `<form>` element because it is designed to be placed within a form.

How can I get access to the `$dirty` property of these checkboxes within the component's controller, since I don't have a reference to the form?

Comment: You could probably use [`ngForm`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm), which is designed for precisely this purpose (nesting of forms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `ng-form` angular directive to group anything, even outside a html form. Then, you can take advantage from angular FormController. Example:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form name="myForm">
  <input name="myInput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="bindTo" ng-maxlength="5">
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.myInput.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
</div>
```